# SQL query has me stumped

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select

Here is my situation: I have two tables, table A has columns:

```
  ID,
  Name,
  ClassYear,
  Classmonth
```

`ID` is the primary key no duplicates.

Table b has these columns:

```
    ID,
    addresstype
    addline1
    addline2
    country,
    city,
    state,
    zip
```

`ID` is not unique in `table B` but it is how you link back to `table A`.

If you have more than one `address` e.g. `Home`, `school` then you have more than on record in `table b`.

My task is to select everyone from `table A` that has a `class year` that is `>= 2019` and everyone that has a `class year = 2018` as long as the `class month` is `>=5`

I got that no problem.

Where it gets confusing to me is now that I have this list of people from `table A` I need to query `table b` and I only want to pull those who have both a `home` and `school` address types and the addresses are identical e.g. `line 1`, `line 2`, `country`, `city`, `state`, `zip` are identical.

I would greatly appreciate some insight.

Comment: Can you post what you tried so far? This should be solvable using JOIN and then using WHERE to put some restrictions on both tables, but it will be easier to figure out if you post what you have now.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to learn how to ask a question with a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT
    student.ID
    , student.Name
    , student.ClassYear
    , student.ClassMonth
FROM
    TableA AS student
    INNER JOIN TableB AS homeAddress ON
        student.ID = homeAddress.ID
        AND homeAddress.addressType = 'Home'
    INNER JOIN TableB AS schoolAddress ON
        student.ID = schoolAddress.ID
        AND schoolAddress.addressType = 'School'
        AND homeAddress.line1 = schoolAddress.line1
        AND homeAddress.line2 = schoolAddress.line2
        AND homeAddress.country = schoolAddress.country
        AND homeAddress.city = schoolAddress.city
        AND homeAddress.state = schoolAddress.state
        AND homeAddress.zip = schoolAddress.zip
WHERE
    student.classYear >= 2019
    OR (student.ClassYear = 2018 AND student.classMonth >= 5)
;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could group by the address' details and count the number of distinct types it has:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1
WHERE  id IN (SELECT   id
              FROM     table2
              WHERE    addresstype IN ('home', 'school')
              GROUP BY id, addline1, addline2, country, city, state, zip
              HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT addresstype) = 2)
```

Comment: @ZoharPeled  eep, indeed! Thanks for noticing. Edited and fixed.